# linear probing vs separate chaining in hashes

Tags: hash

I am well aware that there's another question about this, but my question is different.

I know for sure that searching using separate chaining will us O(N/M) and if we sort the lists we get O( log(N/M)).

However the running time of searching or deleting using linear probing is not clear to me. As far as I know it is the load factor but that's it.

Additionally, when we have cases like a full array (worst case), is it better to use separate chain or linear probing?
If we have a sparse array, which one is to choose as well?

I can't seem to figure out where the advantages of them over each other.

thank you